# how can we resample time series in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'd like to use the [bucket](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprDateTimeNameSpace.buckets.html?highlight=downsampling) expression with groupby, to downsample on monthly basis, as the [downsampling](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.downsample.html?highlight=downsampling) function will be deprecated. Is there a easy way to do this, datetime.timedelta only works on days and lower.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the landing `groupby_dynamic` we can now downsample and use the whole expression API for our aggregations. Meaning we can `resample` by either.

- upsampling
- downsampling
- first upsample and then downsample

Let's go through an example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"time": pl.date_range(low=datetime(2021, 12, 16), high=datetime(2021, 12, 16, 3), interval="30m"),
     "groups": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a"],
     "values": [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.]
    })

print(df)
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ time                ┆ groups ┆ values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ datetime            ┆ str    ┆ f64    │
╞═════════════════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 2021-12-16 00:00:00 ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 00:30:00 ┆ a      ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 01:00:00 ┆ a      ┆ 3      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 01:30:00 ┆ b      ┆ 4      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:00:00 ┆ b      ┆ 5      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:30:00 ┆ a      ┆ 6      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 03:00:00 ┆ a      ┆ 7      │
└─────────────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

## Upsampling

Upsampling can be done by defining an interval. This will yield a `DataFrame` with nulls, which can then be filled with a fill strategy or interpolation.

```py
df.upsample("time", "15m").fill_null("forward")
```

```
shape: (13, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ time                ┆ groups ┆ values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ datetime            ┆ str    ┆ f64    │
╞═════════════════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 2021-12-16 00:00:00 ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 00:15:00 ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 00:30:00 ┆ a      ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 00:45:00 ┆ a      ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...    ┆ ...    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:00:00 ┆ b      ┆ 5      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:15:00 ┆ b      ┆ 5      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:30:00 ┆ a      ┆ 6      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:45:00 ┆ a      ┆ 6      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 03:00:00 ┆ a      ┆ 7      │
└─────────────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

```py
(df.upsample("time", "15m")
   .interpolate()
   .fill_null("forward")  # string columns cannot be interpolated
)
```

```
shape: (13, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ time                ┆ groups ┆ values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ datetime            ┆ str    ┆ f64    │
╞═════════════════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 2021-12-16 00:00:00 ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 00:15:00 ┆ a      ┆ 1.5    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 00:30:00 ┆ a      ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 00:45:00 ┆ a      ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...    ┆ ...    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:00:00 ┆ b      ┆ 5      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:15:00 ┆ b      ┆ 3.5    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:30:00 ┆ a      ┆ 6      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 02:45:00 ┆ a      ┆ 4      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-16 03:00:00 ┆ a      ┆ 7      │
└─────────────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

## Downsampling

This is the powerful one, because we can also combine this with normal groupby keys. Having a virtual moving window over the time series (grouped by one or multiple keys) that can be aggregated with the expression API.

```py
(df.groupby_dynamic(
    time_column="time", 
    every="1h", 
    closed="both", 
    by="groups", 
    include_boundaries=True
)
    .agg([
        pl.col('time').count(), 
        pl.col("time").max(),
        pl.sum("values"),
    ]))
```

```
shape: (4, 7)
┌────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ groups ┆ _lower_bou ┆ _upper_bou ┆ time       ┆ time_count ┆ time_max            ┆ values_sum │
│ ---    ┆ ndary      ┆ ndary      ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---                 ┆ ---        │
│ str    ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ datetime   ┆ u32        ┆ datetime            ┆ f64        │
│        ┆ datetime   ┆ datetime   ┆            ┆            ┆                     ┆            │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ a      ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 3          ┆ 2021-12-16 01:00:00 ┆ 6          │
│        ┆ 00:00:00   ┆ 01:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   ┆            ┆                     ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a      ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 1          ┆ 2021-12-16 00:00:00 ┆ 1          │
│        ┆ 01:00:00   ┆ 02:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   ┆            ┆                     ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a      ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2          ┆ 2021-12-16 03:00:00 ┆ 13         │
│        ┆ 02:00:00   ┆ 03:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   ┆            ┆                     ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b      ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2021-12-16 ┆ 2          ┆ 2021-12-16 02:00:00 ┆ 9          │
│        ┆ 01:00:00   ┆ 02:00:00   ┆ 01:00:00   ┆            ┆                     ┆            │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: We also plan dynamic groupby on not time related columns, meaning that you can use it for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377100/use-the-rolling-function-of-polars-to-get-a-list-of-all-values-in-the-rolling-wi

Comment: that's great ty!

Comment: I noticed, that an capacity overflow error is thrown when the dataframe isn't sorted by dates, maybe this should be documented some where.

Comment: I believe that's a bug. Can you make an issue?

The documentation already states that the `time_column` must be sorted.

Comment: I made a issue, ty for your great support!.  I completly overlooked the part of the documentation which stats that, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solutuion for my problem using the [round](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprDateTimeNameSpace.round.html?highlight=round#polars.internals.expr.ExprDateTimeNameSpace.round) expression and a groupby operation on the date column after it.

Here is some Code exmaple:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
{
    "A": [
        "2020-01-01",
        "2020-01-02",
        "2020-02-03",
        "2020-02-04",
        "2020-03-05",
        "2020-03-06",
        "2020-06-06",
    ],
    "B": [1.0, 8.0, 6.0, 2.0, 16.0, 10.0,2],
    "C": [3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 2.0, 13.0, 8.0,2],
    "D": [12.0, 5.0, 9.0, 2.0, 11.0, 2.0,2],
}
)
q = (
    df.lazy().with_column(pl.col('A').str.strptime(pl.Date, "%Y-%m-%d").dt.round(rule='month',n=1))
        .groupby('A').agg(
                [pl.col("B").max(),
                pl.col("C").min(),
                 pl.col("D").last()]
            )
        .sort('A')
)
df = q.collect()
print(df)
```

prints

```
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬────────┐
│ A          ┆ B_max ┆ C_min ┆ D_last │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ date       ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64    │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 ┆ 8     ┆ 3     ┆ 5      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-02-01 ┆ 6     ┆ 2     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-03-01 ┆ 16    ┆ 8     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-06-01 ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2      │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Some explanation, first I cast the String column to pl.Date type, then I use .dt to create the Namespace of the Date Types. After that I use the round function of the DateTime Namespace to round all Dates on monthly basis to the first day in the month. As result every date in the same month got the same date, so I can group them with groupby and use some aggregation functions on the groups. The downside of this method(and downsampling too) is that u missing the months where no dates exist. For this u can us this code, it's a little bit messy and I had to use pandas but I think it works.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
date_min = df['A'].dt.min()
date_max = df['A'].dt.max()+relativedelta(months=+1)
t_index=pd.date_range(date_min, date_max, freq='M',closed='right').values
t_index = [datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(str(np.datetime_as_string(x, unit='D'))) for x in t_index]
df_ref = pl.DataFrame(t_index,columns='A')
q=(
    df_ref.lazy().with_column(pl.col('A').cast(pl.Date).dt.round(rule='month',n=1))
    .join(df.lazy(),on='A',how='left')
)
df = q.collect()
print(df)
```

results in

```
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬────────┐
│ A          ┆ B_max ┆ C_min ┆ D_last │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ date       ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64    │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 ┆ 8     ┆ 3     ┆ 5      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-02-01 ┆ 6     ┆ 2     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-03-01 ┆ 16    ┆ 8     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-04-01 ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-05-01 ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-06-01 ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2      │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: i've added some example, i hope this helps, maybe u got some better and cleaner idea for the last part :)