# Use the rolling function of polars to get a list of all values in the rolling windows

Tags: python, python-polars

I'd like to use the rolling function to get a list of all values in the rolling windows.

I tried it with follwing code snippet:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1.0, 2.0, 9.0, 2.0, 13.0],
    }
)

df.select(
    [
        pl.col("A").rolling_apply(3, lambda s: s),
    ]
)
```

this outputs

```
┌──────┐
│ A    │
│ ---  │
│ f64  │
╞══════╡
│ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9    │
└──────┘
```

but what I need is:

```
┌─────────────────┐
│ A               │
│ ---             │
│ list [f64]      │
╞═════════════════╡
│ [null, null, 1] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [null, 1, 2]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1, 2, 9]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [2, 9, 2]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [9, 2, 13]      │
└─────────────────┘
```

Does anyone got a idea how to do this in polars in a easy way?

Comment: can you add imports and error messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create lagged columns and collect them into a list.

```py
(df
    .with_columns([pl.col("A").shift(i).alias(f"A_lag_{i}") for i in range(3)])
    .select(
        [pl.concat_list([f"A_lag_{i}" for i in range(3)][::-1]).alias("A_rolling")]
))
```

Outputs:

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ A_rolling       │
│ ---             │
│ list [f64]      │
╞═════════════════╡
│ [null, null, 1] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [null, 1, 2]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1, 2, 9]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [2, 9, 2]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [9, 2, 13]      │
└─────────────────┘
```

Let's break it down:

`reshape(-1, 1)` converts `"A"` into a list.

`pl.col(..).shift(i) for i in range(3)]` creates the new lagged columns.

This results in this intermediate DataFrame:

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ A   ┆ A_lag_0    ┆ A_lag_1    ┆ A_lag_2    │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ f64 ┆ list [f64] ┆ list [f64] ┆ list [f64] │
╞═════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1]        ┆ [null]     ┆ [null]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ [2]        ┆ [1]        ┆ [null]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9   ┆ [9]        ┆ [2]        ┆ [1]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ [2]        ┆ [9]        ┆ [2]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13  ┆ [13]       ┆ [2]        ┆ [9]        │
└─────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Finally we concat them in reversed order and name the output "A_rolling":

`pl.concat_list([f"A_lag_{i}" for i in range(3)][::-1]).alias("A_rolling")`

Comment: Would the temporary columns be allocated in memory? (even if it would operate on LazyFrame?) I guess if so, this would not be a feasible solution for large datasets where the lag is large.

Comment: I've update the answer so that we first create  the list and then the lagged columns.

The lags are slices of the original column, they don't allocate memory and are super cheap.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is that `lambda s: s` leads to `rolling_apply` selecting the last element. There does not seem to be a way to have it return multiple elements at the moment. For instance, when I try to force it to a list using `lambda s: list(s)` instead, it will raise an error that a list cannot be returned, suggesting that this functionality is not present.

Below a workaround involving a Python loop (so slow), but may help you:

Define a custom `slice` function:

```py
def _slice(s: pl.Series, offset: int, l: int) -> pl.Series:
    # like s.slice(offset, l), but prepadding with null when offset <0
    if offset < 0:
        prepad = pl.Series([None] * abs(offset))
        return pl.concat((prepad, s.slice(0, l+offset)))
    else:
        return s.slice(offset, l)
```

And use that to loop over `df["A"]`:

```py
l = 3
pl.Series([_slice(df["A"], n-l+1, l) for n in range(len(df))])
```

which results in:

```
shape: (5,)
Series: '' [list]
[
    [null, null, 1]
    [null, 1, 2]
    [1, 2, 9]
    [2, 9, 2]
    [9, 2, 13]
]
```

This is by no means a performant solution, so the question here is what will you do with the lists inside the dataframe? Storing data in this format is usually going to be a challenge for further processing.

Comment: ty for ur answer, I'm trying to translate a pandas code(it's not my code)  to polars. The pandas code has as end result a column with a list datatype and saved it to a file. I'm not realy happy with it either^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rolling`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html) for that.

So, taking your example DataFrame as input:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1.0, 2.0, 9.0, 2.0, 13.0],}
)

df.rolling(
    index_column=pl.int_range(0, len(df)), period="3i"
).agg(
    pl.col('A').first(),
    pl.col('A').alias('data')
).drop('literal').with_columns(
    pl.col('data')
    .list.reverse()
    .list.gather(pl.arange(0, 3), null_on_oob=True)
    .list.reverse()
)

┌─────┬───────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ data              │
│ --- ┆ ---               │
│ f64 ┆ list[f64]         │
╞═════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ [null, null, 1.0] │
│ 1.0 ┆ [null, 1.0, 2.0]  │
│ 1.0 ┆ [1.0, 2.0, 9.0]   │
│ 2.0 ┆ [2.0, 9.0, 2.0]   │
│ 9.0 ┆ [9.0, 2.0, 13.0]  │
└─────┴───────────────────┘
```

Let's brake it down. The core part of it is using `rolling()` to get your lists :

```py
print(df.rolling(
    index_column=pl.int_range(0, len(df)), period="3i"
).agg(
    pl.col('A').first(),
    pl.col('A').alias('data')
).drop('literal'))

┌─────┬──────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ data             │
│ --- ┆ ---              │
│ f64 ┆ list[f64]        │
╞═════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ [1.0]            │
│ 1.0 ┆ [1.0, 2.0]       │
│ 1.0 ┆ [1.0, 2.0, 9.0]  │
│ 2.0 ┆ [2.0, 9.0, 2.0]  │
│ 9.0 ┆ [9.0, 2.0, 13.0] │
└─────┴──────────────────┘
```

After that you only need to pad your lists with nulls, and for that we can use [`gather()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.list.gather.html). The problem with it is that it's going to pad the resulting lists with nulls from the right, so to overcome it we can use [`reverse()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.list.reverse.html).