# polars - take a window of N rows surrounding a row fulfilling a condition

Tags: python-polars

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "letters": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"],
    "values": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh"]
})

print(df)
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────────┬────────┐
│ letters ┆ values │
│ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ str     ┆ str    │
╞═════════╪════════╡
│ A       ┆ aa     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B       ┆ bb     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C       ┆ cc     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ D       ┆ dd     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ E       ┆ ee     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ F       ┆ ff     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ G       ┆ gg     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ H       ┆ hh     │
└─────────┴────────┘
```

How do I take a window of size +/- N around any row that satisfies a given condition? For example, the condition is `pl.col("letters").contains("D|F")` and `N = 2`. Then, the output should be:

```
┌─────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ letters ┆ output                         │
│ ---     ┆ ---                            │
│ str     ┆ list[str]                      │
╞═════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ D       ┆ ["bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ F       ┆ ["dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh"] │
└─────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note that the windows are overlapping in this case (the `F` window also contains `dd` and the `D` windows also contains `ff`). Also, note that N = 2 for the sake of simplicity here but, in reality, it'll be larger (~10 - 20). And the dataset is relatively large so I'd like to do this as efficiently as possible without exploding memory usage.

---

**EDIT:** To make the ask more explicit, here's the query in DuckDB's SQL syntax that gives the right answer (and I'd like to know how to translate it to Polars):

```py
df_table = df.to_arrow()
con = duckdb.connect()
query = """
SELECT
    letters,
    list(values) OVER (
        ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING
                 AND 2 FOLLOWING
    ) as combined
FROM df_table
QUALIFY letters in ('D', 'F')
"""
print(pl.from_arrow(con.execute(query).arrow()))

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ letters ┆ combined               │
│ ---     ┆ ---                    │
│ str     ┆ list[str]              │
╞═════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ D       ┆ ["bb", "cc", ... "ff"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ F       ┆ ["dd", "ee", ... "hh"] │
└─────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

---

## Benchmarks of suggested solutions

I ran the suggested solutions in a Jupyter notebook on one of Amazon's `ml.c5.xlarge` machines. While the notebook was running, I also kept `htop` open in a terminal to observe CPU and memory use. The dataset had 12M+ rows.

I ran both solutions via both the eager and lazy APIs. For good measure, I also tried using a simple Python for loop to extract the slices after identifying the rows of interest and also DuckDB.

### Summary Table

Polars had really robust performance and judicious memory use (with the @jqurious' method) because of the clever, no-copy implementation of `.shift()` . Surprisingly, a well-thought out Python for loop did just as well. DuckDB had performed rather poorly in both speed and memory use.

Neither Polars nor DuckDB uses more than one core for the operation. Not sure if that's due to a lack of optimization or if this problem is just amenable to parallelization. I suppose we're only filtering over one column and then taking slices of that same column so there's not much multiple threads can do.

| method | cpu use | memory use | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ | single core | explosion |  |
| jqurious | single core | 2.53G to 2.53G | 4.63 s |
| (smart) for loop | single core | 2.53G to 2.58G | 4.91 s |
| DuckDB | single core | 1.62G to 6.13G | 38.6 s |

- cpu use shows if multiple cores were taxes during the operation
- memory use shows how much memory was being used before the operation and the maximum memory use during the operation.

### @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ's solution:

```
preceding = 2
following = 2

look_around = [pl.col("body").shift(-i)
               for i in range(-preceding, following + 1)]

(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('body').str.contains(regex))
        .then(pl.concat_list(look_around))
        .alias('combined')
    )
    .filter(pl.col('combined').is_not_null())
)
```

Unfortunately, on my rather large dataset, this solution caused the memory use to explode and the kernel to crash with both the eager and lazy APIs.

### @jqurious' solution

```
preceding = 2
following = 2

look_around = [
    pl.col("body").shift(-i).alias(f"lag_{i}") for i in range(-preceding, following + 1)
]

(
   df
    .with_columns(
      look_around
    )
    .filter(pl.col("body").str.contains(regex))
    .select([
      pl.col("body"),
      pl.concat_list([f"lag_{i}" for i in range(-2, 3)]).alias("output")
    ])
)
```

- **eager:**

  - **cpu use:** single-core
  - **memory use:** 2.53G -> 2.53G
  - **time:** 4.63 s ± 6.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- **lazy:**

  - **cpu use:** single-core
  - **memory use:** 2.53G -> 2.53G
  - **time:** 4.63 s ± 3.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

### (Smart) Python for loop

```
preceding = 2
following = 2

output = []

indices = df.with_row_count().select(
    pl.col("row_nr").filter(pl.col("body").str.contains(regex))
)["row_nr"]

for idx, x in enumerate(indices):
    offset = max(0, x - preceding)
    length = preceding + following + 1
    output.append(df["body"].slice(offset, length))
```

- **cpu use:** single-core
- **memory use:** 2.53G -> 2.58G
- **time:** 4.91 s ± 24.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

### DuckDB

Note that I first converted the `df` to an `Arrow.Table` before running the query so DuckDB could directly act on it. Also, I'm not sure if the conversion of the result back to Arrow takes up a huge amount of computation and is unfair to it.

```
preceding = 2
following = 2

query = f"""
SELECT
    body,
    list(body) OVER (
        ROWS BETWEEN {preceding} PRECEDING
                 AND {following} FOLLOWING
    ) as combined
FROM df_table
QUALIFY regexp_matches(body, '{regex}')
"""

result = con.execute(query).arrow()
```

With DuckDB, my first attempt to run the computation crashed. I had to retry by reading to an Arrow Table directly without using Polars (this saved about 1GB of memory) to give DuckDB more memory to use.

- **first try:**

  - **cpu:** single-core
  - **memory:** 2.53G -> 6.93G -> crash!
  - **time:** NA
- **second try:**

  - **cpu:** single-core
  - **memory:** 1.62G -> 6.13G
  - **time:** 38.6 s ± 311 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70406291 - lagged shifted columns are slices and don't allocate memory.

Comment: Understood, thanks! However, I'm still not sure about the syntax I'd use to get the answer I want. Compared to that problem, I also have a conditional query + I need to look backwards and not just forwards. Any ideas on that front would be appreciated!

Comment: You can modify the `range()` to look back and use `.filter()` - I've added a modification below - there may be a better way.

Comment: @anonymous1a it is still in alpha, but could you try a lazy run an see if `collect(allow_streaming=True)` improves the performance?

It should parallelize the regex search.

Comment: @ritchie46 It didn't really make much of a difference. My actual application also requires searching for multiple keywords (~200) so my regex search is actually pretty large. I tried two methods: concatenating them all into one string with `"|"` and create a polars filter Expr per keyword and then reducing them with the `|` operator. The second option reduce the runtime somewhat (2min 36s to 2min 5s). The second method also used all 4 cores. However, `allow_streaming=True` made no difference to parallelization or the time it took to run the query.  DuckDB actually won now: 43s only.

Comment: Here's the code for the two approaches: https://pastebin.com/99zc41gv Maybe you can help me figure out how to improve the query for parallelization or if I'm not using `allow_streaming` properly.

Comment: @anonymous1a You may be interested in adding another duckdb approach using `lag()` and `lead()` to the benchmark: https://pastebin.com/raw/kLUNBWRz - it seems to outperform the `qualify` approach in local testing.

Comment: @jqurious Thanks! That was really helpful and reduced the runtime for even the complex (50+ keywords) regex from 43s to 11s. It's weird that the more 'canonical' way of doing lead/lag is not as efficient as explicitly listing columns. This could probably be optimized by DuckDB (I'll create an issue.) I also noticed that while DuckDB uses a lot of memory, it's regex filters are independent of the complexity of the regex: whether it's one keyword or 50, the compute time is the same. This is where polars struggle a lot (compute time goes from 5s to 2min 5s) for a more complex pattern.

Comment: @anonymous1a Yeah the `QUALIFY` happens AFTER the window expression - so its creating the `list(values)` for all rows then filtering. It took a while for me to realize how to use lag/lead first - it seems there should be a simpler way to write this type of thing. Very interesting problem - seems like it can be a useful benchmark for both projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modification of [Use the rolling function of polars to get a list of all values in the rolling windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377100/use-the-rolling-function-of-polars-to-get-a-list-of-all-values-in-the-rolling-wi/70406291#70406291)

```
>>> (
...    df
...    .with_columns(
...       [pl.col("values").shift(i).alias(f"lag_{i}") for i in range(-2, 3)])
...    .filter(pl.col("letters").str.contains("D|F"))
...    .select([
...       pl.col("letters"),
...       pl.concat_list(reversed([f"lag_{i}" for i in range(-2, 3)])).alias("output")
...    ])
... )
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ letters | output                         │
│ ---     | ---                            │
│ str     | list[str]                      │
╞═════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ D       | ["bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"] │
├─────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ F       | ["dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh"] │
└─//──────┴─//─────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Awesome! In my benchmarks (see the edited OP), this was the most robust solution and didn't increase memory consumption the slightest bit, even when dealing with a 12M rows table! I wonder if the results from concat_list are also no-copy operations and just views of the relevant cells (that would seem to be the case given that there was basically no change in memory use whatsoever).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```py
preceding = 2
following = 2

look_around = [pl.col("values").shift(-i)
               for i in range(-preceding, following + 1)]

(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('letters').str.contains('D|F'))
        .then(pl.concat_list(look_around))
        .alias('combined')
    )
    .filter(pl.col('combined').is_not_null())
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────┬────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ letters ┆ values ┆ combined               │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---                    │
│ str     ┆ str    ┆ list[str]              │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ D       ┆ dd     ┆ ["bb", "cc", ... "ff"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ F       ┆ ff     ┆ ["dd", "ee", ... "hh"] │
└─────────┴────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution worked for this toy example but when dealing with a larger dataframe, it unfortunately causes memory explosion and caused my kernel to crash. I'm guessing that Polars is first materialising multiple copies of the column before filtering. The column is a long (12M rows) and has relatively long unicode strings so I'm guessing those copies are causing issues.